# ember data REST change JSON

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

I am using ember-data 1.0.0-beta.4. On update it sends PUT request with following JSON

> {"property": { "name":"name", "age":"22" } }

How can change my RESTAdapter to send following JSON instead of above

> { "name":"name", "age":"22" }

Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

create a custom serializer and override the `serializeIntoHash` hook, something like this should do it (I didn't test this).

Read more about serializers here: https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/TRANSITION.md

```
App.PropertySerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
    var root = Ember.String.decamelize(type.typeKey),
        properties = this.serialize(record, options);
    for(var prop in properties){
      if(properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        data[prop] = properties[prop];
      }
    }
  }
});
```