# Ember Data hasMany relationship empty result

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I'm using:

- `ember-cli` `0.2.7`
- `ember-data` `1.0.0-beta.18`
- `ember` `1.12.0`

I'm not sure why but it seems that I can't retrieve the tags for my `newsletter` model.

I'm using `ActiveModelAdapter`:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: 'http://localhost:3000'
});
```

newsletter.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.hasMany('tag')
});
```

tag.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
});
```

API response (rails backend using ActiveModelSerializer):

```
{
  "newsletters": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Panel Weekly",
      "tag_ids": [
        1
      ]
    },
    {...}
  ],
  "tags": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "arts"
    },
    {...}
}
```

I don't know how to retrieve the list of tags for a newsletter. I tried this using the ember inspector and the console ($E containing the first newsletter):

```
>$E.get('tags.length')
0
>$E.get('tags')
Class {canonicalState: Array[0], store: Class, relationship: ember$data$lib$system$relationships$state$has$many$$ManyRelationship, record: Class, currentState: Array[0]…}
>$E.get('title')
"Panel Weekly"
```

Comment: Try to add `newsletter_id: 1` to tags payload, since `newsletter: DS.belongsTo('newsletter', {async: true})`

Comment: I have edited my answer I don't thing the relation in the tag model is relevant and it is also probably incorrect because a tag hasMany newsletters. There is enough info in the payload to match tags and newsletters.

Comment: What is Ember-Data version? You are using DS.ActiveModelAdapter, right?

Comment: You are using the ActiveModelAdapter in Ember, correct?

Comment: Yes and the ember-data version is: `1.0.0-beta.18`

Comment: Do you see tags uploaded in Ember.Inspector "Data"?

Comment: @Artysh Yes all the tags are loaded into the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reproduced your situation in a JSBin and it works fine:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/yeboqe/3/edit?html,js,output

Your problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, for that I'm gonna take a look at it and check what going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that I was using a custom serializer for my newsletter model that was not necessary. Just removing the file solved the problem ><.

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

// http://stackoverflow.com/a/21075106/1447468
export default DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
    var properties = this.serialize(record, options);
    for(var prop in properties){
      if(properties.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        data[prop] = properties[prop];
      }
    }
  }
});
```